# How to load image list from REST API using angularJS

Tags: image, rest, angularjs

I have searched in this forum for quiet a bit and here's my problem -

I have a ng-repeat in my html which takes in a list of messages(Json object).
Each message JSON has a sender email address - e.g. abc@gmail.com

Now, I have to get the email address from the message and form another REST API request to fetch their images for e.g. - http://<>:8080/getImage/abc@gmail.com (email address dynamic)

So in my code, I'll have a ng-repeat and a ng-src pointing to the image REST URL
If there's no image in server, it returns a 404 and displays a broken image on the UI. How do I handle it? On the other hand, if I make a http request to determine if there's a success message and on failure return a default image, then the whole thing goes through an endless loop. I'll try to create a fiddle and include it for better explanation.

Comment: I'd recommend you check in the browser JS/Network console what urls you are requesting, iy could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the error block to handle such behavior:

```
 function($http) {
                var restUrl = 'getImage/abc';

                return {

    fetchImage: function(imageId) {
                        var self = this;
                        return  $http.get(restUrl + '/' + imageId).
                            success(function(data) {
                                return self.imageUrl = data;
                            }).
                            error(function(data) {
                                return self.imageUrl = "pathToDefaultImage";
                            });
                    },

    ...
```